# filtrar consulta con valores repetidos solo mostrar 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buen dia

tengo esta consulta

```
$eventos_history_query = tep_db_query("select * from " .
 TABLE_HISTORIAL . " where numero_evento = '" .
 $customers['numero_evento'] . "' order by eventos");

 while ($eventos_history = tep_db_fetch_array($eventos_history_query))
 {
```

en un TABLE_HISTORIAL y existe valores repetidos en la tabla notas,

en este ejemplo vemos que nota1 se repite 3 veces:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo quiero mostrar la primera nota1 siempre y cuando sea distinta a las demas ejemplo:

resultado deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como realizo el query para que desaparezcan la nota1 del evento2 y evento3 ya que esta repetido en evento1 ? solo a nivel de consulta en pantalla

Comment: Con 'group by notas' en la consulta agrupas por el campo notas o como le hayas llamado.

Comment: @Carmen pero si hace un group by se le van a ocultar evento 2 y evento 3, que hasta donde se ve en resultado deseado si requiere salgan

Comment: no funciona solo me muestra: evento1 nota1, evento4 nota2 y evento5 nota3 los valores evento2 nota1 y evento3 nota1 los borra

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez ¿has contemplado hacerlo en código en vez de en la consulta? Lo digo porque es mucho mas sencillo.

Comment: ni idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: lo que necesito es pintar la imagen 2 mantengo todos los eventos pero la nota1 como se repite en varios solo muestre el primer resultado,

Comment: entendí mal, creí que querías que no apareciera el registro, en ese caso es mejor en código php al recorrer los resultados

Answer (score 2):

Al recorrer los resultados, almacenas la nota en una variable y la muestras sólo cuando es diferente de la anteriror.

```
$lastnota = "";
while ($eventos_history = tep_db_fetch_array($eventos_history_query)) {
   //comprobamos si la nota se repite
   if ($lastnota != "" && $lastnota==$eventos_history->nota) {
     $nota = "";
   } else {
     $nota = $eventos_history->nota;
   }
   //imprimes tu resultado - aplica al formato que tengas para mostrarlo
   echo $eventos_history->evento." - ".$nota;
   //actualizamos la variables que alamacena la última nota
   $lastnota =  $eventos_history->nota;
}
```